# How to convert electrical power loss into heat loss?

Tags: temperature

Calculations to convert power loss into heat loss where the temperature rise in material is unknown due to current flow. I couldnt get the formulae which doesnot contain temperature parameter.

Comment: Power is Watts and you can express Watts as Joules per unit time.

Comment: Look at : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22334/how-do-i-calculate-the-temperature-rise-in-a-copper-conductor

Answer (score 1):

Power loss is measured in watts, or joules/second.

Heat loss is measured in joules, or watt*seconds.

Neither involves temperature as a parameter. The conversion factor is the time over which the loss occurs.

If however you are using 'heat' as a synonym for temperature, then 'temperature loss' might be calculated by using the thermal capacity of an object over the rate at which it's losing heat energy, times time.